# Casting series as string-type -- current strategies aren't working

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting a type when splitting a column of my dataframe, but I can't seem to cast the column as string type to fix it. The series is currently an object-type.

```
for idx, row in enumerate(df.top_5_investors):
    for item in row.split(", "):
        df3.loc[idx, item] = 1

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I've tried a number of different approaches and found answers on this site that, but data type is still object:

```
df.astype(str)['top_5_investors'].map(lambda x:  type(x))
```

```
df.top_5_investors.fillna('')
```

The desired result would turn the entire column 'top_5_investors' into string-type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `astype` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) of pandas, you can use it to convert your `df.top_5_investors` to a string columns

```
df['top_5_investors'] = df.top_5_investors.astype(str)
```